# I want to create a scanning shader, using two cameras

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to create a scanning shader, using two cameras. My main camera is rendering characters and the depth-only or don't-clear camera is rendering the scanner tool the issue is that when I change the tool layer to the main camera the shader starts working but when I change the tool layer to the tool camera then the shader stops working. here are my shaders.

```
Shader "Custom/Scanner"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Geometry-1" }  // Write to the stencil buffer before drawing any geometry to the screen
        ColorMask 0 // Don't write to any colour channels
        ZWrite Off // Don't write to the Depth buffer
        Stencil
        {
            Ref 1
            Comp Always
            Pass Replace
        }
        Pass
        {

        }
    }
}
```

```
Shader "Custom/XrayChar"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
    }
    SubShader
    {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Pass
        {
            Tags { "Queue" = "Overlay" "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
            //LOD 200
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1 // ReferenceValue = 1
                Comp Equal // Only render pixels whose reference value differs from the value in the buffer.
            }
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                //float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };
            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Return color output for second pass
                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
        Pass
        {
            Tags{ "Queue" = "Overlay" "IgnoreProjector" = "False" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1
                Comp NotEqual
            }
            Lighting Off
            ZWrite Off
            ZTest Off
            Cull Off
            //ColorMask 0     // do not write to the frame buffer
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I want a solution depend on my requirements.